# How to send firebase IDToken from Angular Interceptor without AngularFire library?

Tags: angular, firebase-authentication

I want to send Firebase IDToken with every http request from my Angular App. I'm using AngularFire library as of now and interceptor is working as expected. I want to remove AngularFire library and just want to use Firebase. How can I achieve same result? Below is my current implementation:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class RequestInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  constructor(private af: AngularFireAuth) {}
  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    return this.af.idToken.pipe(
      mergeMap((token: string) => {
        if(!req.url.includes('auth')) {
          req = req.clone({
            setHeaders: {
              Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`
            }
          });
        }
        return next.handle(req);

      })
    );
  }
}
```

Is there a way I can use plain firebase library to achieve same functionality?

Answer (score 1):

I think I've found a way to resolve that. But, I'm not 100% sure if it is a optimum solution. I would appreciate if you guys can review below code:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ReqInterceptorService implements HttpInterceptor {
  constructor() {}
  /*
  * Every outgoing Http request will go through this Http interceptor and append
  * Authorization nav-header to it.
  */
  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    /* Firebase will refresh token automatically if expired */
    return from(this.getCurrentIdToken()).pipe(
      mergeMap(token => {
        console.log(token);
        req = req.clone({
          setHeaders: {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`
          }
        });
        return next.handle(req);
      })
    )
  }

  getCurrentIdToken() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const auth = firebase.auth();
      const unsubscribe = auth.onIdTokenChanged(user => {
        unsubscribe();
        if (user) {
          user.getIdToken().then(token => {
            resolve(token);
          });
        } else {
          reject(null);
        }
      }, reject);
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: This code is working fine for me but I needed to change the reject(null) -> resolve(null).